# Type Hinting pandas DataFrame sliced row's index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm, type-hinting

I've got a Dataframe with `DatetimeIndex` and other columns as below :

```
                     test
datetime                 
2020-01-01 00:10:00     1
2020-01-01 00:20:00     2
2020-01-01 00:30:00     3
2020-01-01 00:40:00     4
```

So I'm gonna get one row of DataFrame :

```
>>> row = df.iloc[0]
>>> print(row)
test    1
Name: 2020-01-01 00:10:00, dtype: int64
```

Now if I wanna access the selected row's index ( That is converted to a `pandas.Series` ) I should access the `name` attribute of `row` :

```
>>> print(row.name)
2020-01-01 00:10:00
>>> print(type(row.name))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

When I'm going to pass this `row.name` to a method as a `pandas.Timestamp` argument , `PyCharm` shows this warning :

```
Expected type 'Timestamp', got 'Optional[Hashable]' instead
```

So Here is my more clarified question :

1. Is there any other way(s) to access sliced row's **index** rather than `row.name` ?
2. How to deal with that warning in `PyCharm` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood fully your case, but you access the index by calling .index, e.g. `df.loc[something].index`, so in your case I would do `df.loc[df.test==1].index` to get the datetime.

Also it seems that your DatetimeIndex is converted to int64. You might have to convert it to timestamp in order to pass it to pd.Timestamp() method.

Comment: THIS IS TOTALLY DIFFERENT FROM WHAT I  ASKED IN OP !

Comment: Is your only goal to access a the name of a pandaseries row or to get the index of the row, which is sliced from a dataframe? In the latter case you can simply do df.index[0]. In the first case, spare the whole description, since it's irrelevant.